The top XML element 'ReservationControlInformationDetailsTypeI' from namespace '' references distinct types
I used svcutil to generate proxy class. I used this proxy class to communicate with Amadeus web services, But when compiling the web service, the error is generated and it is given below.

The top XML element 'ReservationControlInformationDetailsTypeI' from
namespace '' references distinct types
AmadeusService.ServiceReference1.ReservationControlInformationDetailsTypeI15
and
AmadeusService.ServiceReference1.ReservationControlInformationDetailsTypeI14.
Use XML attributes to specify another XML name or namespace for the
element or types.

How can I get rid from above error?.
Thanks in advance
